# Creating new BorderStyle for WinForms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

Is it possible to create a new `BorderStyle` for a control (`Panel`, for example)?

When I use `override OnPaint`, panel children are
able to overlap the border (because border is painted inside control bounds).

Or maybe there is any way to alter `BorderStyle.FixedSingle` color and thickness?

Here is my override event for painting borders of the panel:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnPaint(e);
     ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
         Color.Black, global.bordersize, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
         Color.Black, global.bordersize, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
         Color.Black, global.bordersize, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
         Color.Black, global.bordersize, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);   
 }
```

[image: overlap]

Comment: Set the Padding property of the Panel, then if you Dock Fill the ListBox control for example, it will respect the padding parameters.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this works for the ListBox. Right now, I am adding label controls, and then I am parenting them to the panel. And they are overlapping my custom border. There is the way to fix that by parenting panel without border inside another panel with border, but this method will even more slow down drawing of the controls, and if I will need to interact with label, I will need to interact with TWO more controls, instead of one.

Comment: Dock-Top the label and Dock Fill the ListBox.  Use BringToFront if the controls overlap each other.

Comment: In that example, I do not have a ListBox. Only panel, and labels.

Comment: I have no idea what your first comment was getting at regarding the `interact with TWO more controls instead of one.`  The panel with the border is the one with the padding settings, all of the direct child controls will have to set their dock properties.

Comment: For example I have `label1` that is a child of `panel2` that is a child of `panel1`. How do I interact with `label1` without interacting with `panel1`?

Comment: Label1 doesn't interact with panel1.  If you set the dock or anchor properties of Label1, it will resize or move depending on panel2.

Comment: Well, found a solution: I will just add `panel with border`, set its size to `original panel Width/Height + bordersize*2` and location of `original panel Top/Left - bordersize`. Then I will send it to back. Just wanted the way without including any additional controls, but looks like it is impossible.

Comment: I still don't understand why you would need additional controls.  One panel with the padding is the one that paints your borders, set the dock properties of the child controls.

Comment: Sorry, I am kinda noob >.< So, I have one panel and many labels that are overlapping my border, that is painted on panel's `OnPaint` event. How can I avoid overlapping? (Panel and labels are created and parented dynamically).

Comment: I already told you.  Set the Padding property of the border panel and set the Dock properties of your labels.

Comment: Tried to set panel's padding and dock all controls to top. Nothing changed.

Comment: If you want to draw a real border in non-client area of the panel with custom widths and custom color, you should override `WndProc` and handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and set the border width. Also you should handle `WM_NCPAINT` and `WM_PAINT` and draw border in non-client area. This way the border will be drawn around the panel even when the control have scrollbars.

Comment: As another option to have a thick border around the panel, as a workaround, you can have a panel with desired `BackColor` (as border color, for example black) and desired `Padding` (as border width, for example 5). Then put your main panel in this panel and set the inner panel dock property to fill. Then you will see a thick black border around the inner panel that even if the inner panel have scroll, you can see borders.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Reza. It has something to do with `WndProc`, you are right. But I have no clue how to override it and handle other stuff. I do not wand to add any additional `panels`, because it overloads the program, but for now, this is the only thing that works.